# React Jest test on React Admin coverage left out

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-admin

I was trying to test React Admin, but when I npm run test:coverage. I received the uncovered lines:

| File | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TestCreate.tsx | 55.55 | 100 | 40 | 55.55 | 19-20,32-38 |

It seems it's pointing towards SimpleToolbar method's window.scrollTo and the mutation options onSuccess...

How do I test on these 2?

Below source:

TestCreate.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Create,
  SimpleForm,
  SaveButton,
  useNotify,
  TextInput,
  CreateProps,
  Toolbar,
  required,
} from 'react-admin';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

function SimpleToolbar() {
  const notify = useNotify();
  const { reset } = useFormContext();
  const onSuccess = (data: { email: string }): void => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    notify(`${data.email} submit successfully.`, {
      type: 'success',
      messageArgs: 'form has been submitted',
    });
  };

  return (
    <Toolbar>
      <SaveButton
        type="button"
        label="Submit"
        mutationOptions={{
          onSuccess: (data) => { onSuccess(data); },
        }}
      />
      <Button
        type="reset"
        onClick={() => {
          reset();
        }}
      >
        CLEAR
      </Button>
    </Toolbar>
  );
}

function TestCreate(props: CreateProps) {
  return (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm toolbar={<SimpleToolbar />}>
        <TextInput source="name" label="Name" validate={required()} />
        <TextInput source="email" label="Email" validate={required()} />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
}

export default TestCreate;
```

TestCreate.spec.tsx:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { AdminContext, ResourceContextProvider, testDataProvider } from 'react-admin';

import TestCreate from './TestCreate';

describe('<TestCreate />', () => {
  const dataProvider = testDataProvider({
    create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { name: 'Jason', email: 'jason@gmail.com' } }),
  });
  it('should render components', async () => {
    render(
      <AdminContext dataProvider={dataProvider as any}>
        <ResourceContextProvider value="test">
          <TestCreate />
        </ResourceContextProvider>
      </AdminContext>,
    );

    const nameInput = await screen.findByText('Name');
    expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    const emailInput = await screen.findByText('Email');
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Click on the `<SaveButton>` to trigger the `onSuccess` and test that `notify` and `scrollTo` are called.

Comment: @Arkellys Like how the source code be? I don't see any solution in this, am very new to jest

Comment: I can try to write an answer but I won't be able to test the code so I can't grantee it will works

Answer (score 0):

On your component, the `onSuccess` is called when you click on the `<SaveButton>` and the request is successful. Which means that to test this, you need to trigger a click event on the button and check that what you expect to happen happened.

Assuming you want to test everything, here you expect two things: the `scrollTo` and the `notify`. To test them, you will need to [mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) `useNotify()` and spy on `window.scrollTo`. For the latter, I used the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148351/how-to-spy-on-window-scrollto-in-jest). And for the `useNotify`, you can use use [`mockReturnValue()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-return-values) and write the mock like this:

```
jest.mock("react-admin", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-admin"),
  useNotify: jest.fn();
});
```

You also have to make sure that your `dataProvider` is returning a successful response.

Here is how the test could look like:

```
it("scrolls to the correct position and notifies on success", async () => {
  const mockNotify = jest.fn();
  const scrollToSpy = jest.fn();
  useNotify.mockReturnValue(mockNotify);
  global.scrollTo = scrollToSpy;

  render(
    <AdminContext dataProvider={dataProvider as any}>
      <ResourceContextProvider value="test">
        <TestCreate />
      </ResourceContextProvider>
    </AdminContext>,
  );
  const saveButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Submit" });
  fireEvent.click(saveButton);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(mockNotify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...); // If you want to test the params
    expect(scrollToSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0, 0);
  });
});
```

There are still two things you need to deal with:

- The mock of `useNotify` will also affect your other tests and since
  the code expect `useNotify()` to return a function, you will get an
  error if you don't mock it properly for every test. Whether you
  decide to use a `const` on top of your file, [`beforeEach()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#beforeeachfn-timeout), or
  something else to fix this is up to you.
- Same goes for your mock of the `dataProvider`'s `create`. You only
  mock it once so you might have problem if you need the response on
  multiple tests.

As a side note, I added a [`waitFor()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) because I remember it was sometimes required with RA and these kind of calls. But I think it depends on your code so it might not be necessary.

Comment: I can't test this code so if there are typos or errors we can try to fix them together.